# SSIS permissions for specific databases

Tags: sql-server, ssis, permissions

I'm quite new to SSIS.

Is it a straightforward to grant SSIS permissions in the AD environment so that that a user can only create/manage/run ETL tasks on **specific** databases/Analysis Services projects on a SQL Server that contains **multiple** databases?

I.e. So a user can't extract/load data from/into a database/Analysis services project that they shouldn't etc.

Database version is SQL Server 2012.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to just grant them full admin rights, then yes it is very straightforward.

Comment: Thanks Shawn. Full admin rights for a specific database are a possibility but ideally only partial permissions. Is it specifically tricky to grant SSIS permissions to a specific database/ssas project without giving the user full admin rights to that database?

Comment: just to make sure I understand you want to control the permissions at the ssis task level instead of the database object level?

Comment: Considering that the *Execute SQL Statement Task* is capable of running **any** SQL statement, including for example *DROP DATABASE name*, it will certainly be necessary to define which tasks, on which databases, you wish to allow before one can even consider what permission will have to be granted.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to run the SSIS jobs from the SQL Agent, then they will execute as the user the agent runs as. That's usually the same as the account the instance runs as, which has rights to everything.